# Ошибка при выводе данных из БД Андроид

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Я хочу вывести данные из БД на ListView. Но программа закрывается ошибкой: Unfortunately app has stopped . Уже четвертый раз я вижу эту ошибку и каждый раз с разной причиной. Код вывода из БД:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_passes);

    mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this, "mydatabase.db", null, 1);
    mSqLiteDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();



    ListView siyahi = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);


  Cursor  cursor =  mSqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from "+ DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, null);
    String[] headers = new String[] {DatabaseHelper.SITE_NAME_COLUMN, DatabaseHelper.LOGIN_COLUMN,DatabaseHelper.PASSWORD_COLUMN};
    SimpleCursorAdapter userAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.siyahi_obyekti,
            cursor, headers, new int[]{R.id.textView5, R.id.textView6,R.id.textView7}, 0);
    siyahi.setAdapter(userAdapter);

    cursor.close();
}
```

Из стектрейса понял что причина вот это:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteQuery: select * from yourpass
```

Разметка главного активити (activity_view_passes.xml):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ViewPasses">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView" />
```

Разметка ячейки для ListView (siyahi_obyekti.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Comment: А если убрать `cursor.close();`?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб прав, зачем закрывать курсор сразу после создания? 'ListView' не сможет отобразить данные из закрытого курсора.

Comment: @ЮрийСПБ  а когда я буду закрывать курсор? В методе OnDestroy или как?

Comment: Т.к. У вас активити, то либо в `onStop` либо в `onPause`. Зависит от множества факторов. Вам, думаю, `onStop` подойдёт.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб только сейчас смог проверить Ваш совет и удалил `cursor.close();` Всё работает. Спасибо. Для закрытии курсора использовал вот это:
`@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        cursor.close();
        mSqLiteDatabase.close();

    }`
Базу тоже закрыл. Или не надо?